# Why does squaring an expression with 2 subtracting terms work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

This expression can be simplified as:
$$\sqrt{(x-\frac32)^2} = x - \frac32$$

Even though:
$$k^2 = m^2 + n^2 \to \sqrt{k^2} = \sqrt{m^2 + n^2} \to k = \pm\sqrt{m^2 + n^2}$$

You can not remove the right-hand radical sign in the second example even though it is allowed in the first example.

Why is this so? Why can this be applied to other problems?

Comment: In general, $\;\sqrt[n]{x^n}=|x|\;$ for even $\;n\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square root is a well defined function, in other words, for any element in the domain there is only one unique function value.

When you solve $x^2=9$, you square root both side, that gives you $\sqrt{x^2}=3$ (3 here is the unique value give by the square root).

Then $ \sqrt{x^2}= |x|=3$ , which gives you two possible solution. $x=3$ or $x=-3$

The two solution is due to the definition of an **absolute value**, not by the property of square root function.

Comment: Well... I'd like to think that we *make* the square root function well-defined by choosing for it to always return the *principal* square root (because square roots are not, in general, unique, although the principal square root is).